# MySQL table, Click on Record to select

Tags: php, forms

I have a PHP script that creates a table with the columns `name`, `sales`, and `cert`.
I have an if statement that only displays an icon in the certificate column against the record of the logged in user. All of this works ok.

Now I want to set it up so when the user clicks the displayed certificate icon, it passes `$_POST[year]` and `$_POST[sales]` to the `test.php` script. I'm trying to use the following code snippet to do this, but I'm having problems:

```
$form_start="<form name='test' method='post' action='test.php'>";            
$form_end="</form>";
echo "<td>".$row['year']."&nbsp;</td><td><b>".$row['name']."</b></td><td>".$row['sales']."</td><td>". '<input type="submit"; value='.$row['sales'].'; style="background:url('.$cert_image.'); width: 24px; height: 17px; border: none; no-repeat; />'."</td></tr>";
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

OK I now have the following code:

```
$form_start="<form name='test' method='post' action='test.php'>";            
$form_end="</form>";
echo "<td>".$row['year']."</td><td><b>".$row['name']."</b><input type='hidden'; name='cYear'; value=".$row['year']."/></td><td>".$row['sales']."<input type='hidden'; name='cSales'; value=".$row['sales']." /></td><td><input type='image'; src=$cert_image width: 24px; height: 17px; border: none; no-repeat; alt='Click to revive your Annual Table Certificate'; /></td></tr>";
```

This looks right (at least to me) but when I click on the image file in the table row wanted,nothing happens i.e. the test.php file isn't called by:
    $form_start="";

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Why are there semicolon's in every tag? EG in the form start between `test'` and `'action`?

Comment: Thats my "Bad" I thought there had to be. Removing them makes no difference thought. I'm now able to call test.pgp but my posted values are empty.

Comment: this could all be consolidated into one statement

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget `method="post"` in `<form ... >`:

```
<form name='test' method="post" action='test.php'>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I've now added method='post' which is calling my test.php script but $_POST['year'] and $_POST['sales'] are empty in test.php?

Comment: But where are your <input ... > ?

Comment: Ah just spotted my error. Got it working now. Thanks to al who helped.